com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfOutputStream Error at Itext 8 With Java 8
Can someone help me with extra info about itext's error:
- Flushed object contains indirect reference which is free. Null object will be written instead.


I am trying to modify an existing PDF document,flatten the fields, then add some pages and retrieve it, I just want some general info if someone knows or else I will share the code


The cause is this:  I have a pdf document with 5 pages that i want to
have each one of them twice, so I used Acrobat Pro to copy the 5 pages
and create a new document with 10 pages. Then I modify it with Java and Itext
and this error occurs. So maybe now someone could figure out the cause
and help with the solution


the thing is that pdf is rendered correctly at the end, I just want to find out if it will cause an issue long term

Please read [ask].

Unfortunately it's difficult to tell whether that log output points out an issue for you or not. Having had a look at the iText tests that check for that log line, it looks like this log output occurs when you edit an existing file in a way that deletes an object that still is referenced from somewhere. E.g. you delete a page but there is an outline entry that refers to that page. Obviously any functionality related to that existing reference may be broken. In the example above, the selecting that outline entry does not bring you to the (deleted) page.

I found out the cause, I have a document with 5 pages that i want to have each one of them twice, so I used Acrobat Pro to copy the 5 pages and create a new document with 10 pages. Then I modify it with Java and this error occurs.  So maybe now someone could figure out the cause
